# Storage subsystem borking after server restart (all on a Parallel SCSI bus)

Tags: linux, storage, scsi

I have a server (with a SCSI HBA) connected to two Promise VTrak M310p RAID enclosure on the same bus. Everything is working fine until I have to restart my server. Once restarted, the server can no longer communicate with the enclosures: lots of read errors and bus resets.

I have to turn off both enclosure, then turn off the server, then turn on the enclosure, then turn on the server for things to work.

I don't believe this is the normal behavior, what could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say connected to two promise units, do you mean to separate arrays
or are you using multipath? If it's the later, try just hooking up one path
and try again. Failing that, this sounds like a FW bug, contact Promise.

Comment: I did try that and it works again. Then I reconnect them back to daisy-chain configuration and it also works. I guess it must have been the bus being in a bad state. The unplugging and replugging fixed it.